# Making a request on QMainWindow __init__() without delay the opening

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Im trying to check if a new version of the software is available. That's why I'm making a request. The request can take a time and delay the window's opening.

Should I put this request in a function and call it after the window is loaded? There is a way to make the request in parallel?

I'm using Python 3.

This is an example code:

```
from urllib import request
import json
from pkg_resources import parse_version
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from . import widgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._menu = self.menuBar()
        permanent_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        # This request can take some time
        response = request.urlopen('https://api.github.com/repos/efdiloreto/Zonda/releases/latest')
        data = json.load(response)
        actual_version = '0.1.0'
        release_version = data['tag_name']

        if parse_version(release_version) > parse_version(actual_version):
            permanent_label.setText('A new version is available!')

        status_bar = self.statusBar()
        status_bar.setSizeGripEnabled(False)
        status_bar.addWidget(permanent_label)

        self._widget_central = widgets.MainWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self._widget_central)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request takes time, so there are 2 possible solutions: run it in a thread or use `QNetworkAccessManager` that handles these requests asynchronously, so my answer will use the latter. I see that you are using the GitHub API, so using the docs I have created a class that is responsible for obtaining the version and passing it through a signal.

```
import json
from pkg_resources import parse_version
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtNetwork

# https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-the-latest-release
class LastReleaseGithubHelper(QtCore.QObject):
    versionChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LastReleaseGithubHelper, self).__init__(parent)
        self.fmt = "https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/releases/latest"
        self._manager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager(self)
        self._manager.finished.connect(self.onFinished)

    def get_version(self, owner, repo):
        url = self.fmt.format(owner=owner, repo=repo)
        request = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        self._manager.get(request)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtNetwork.QNetworkReply)
    def onFinished(self, reply):
        response = reply.readAll().data().decode()
        data = json.loads(response)
        release_version = data['tag_name']
        self.versionChanged.emit(release_version)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._menu = self.menuBar()
        self.permanent_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        status_bar = self.statusBar()
        status_bar.setSizeGripEnabled(False)
        status_bar.addWidget(self.permanent_label)

        version_helper = LastReleaseGithubHelper(self)
        version_helper.versionChanged.connect(self.verify_version)

        owner = "efdiloreto"
        repo = "Zonda"
        version_helper.get_version(owner, repo)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def verify_version(self, release_version):
        # only test
        current_version = '0.0.9'
        if parse_version(release_version) > parse_version(current_version):
            self.permanent_label.setText('A new version is available!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. There is a reason for inherit from QObject?

Comment: @Eduardo because if you inherit from QObject you can create signals, in addition you take advantage of the relationship of kinship that is implemented in Qt, remember that the memory of QObjects as the QWidget live in C ++ is not handled by python necessarily. :-)

Comment: Thanks, the code works perfectly. But I'll take my time to study about threads and QNetwork before implement it.

Comment: @Eduardo Do not use threads if there are other tools, that is, use it as a last alternative since many things in Qt are not thread-safe, Qt have many alternatives to avoid using threads.

Comment: I understand. I have a question, if I use QNetworkAccessManager directly, is necesary the creation of LastReleaseGithubHelper class?

Comment: @Eduardo no, it is not necessary, everything you could do in MainWindow but having a lot of code in a class is not good, it is better to divide and specialize

Comment: Thanks for your quick help!

Comment: One last question. QNetworkAccessManager can handle a network connection error? I didn't found documentation about this.

Comment: @Eduardo 
the qnam can tell you the error through signals http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#signals